# Django on python2.5

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-10.10

AppEngine needs Python2.5.
Ubuntu 2010.10 comes with Python 2.6.6 and I didn't want to interfere with it, so I downloaded and compiled Python 2.5 in my home directory.

Then I downloaded Django-1.2.5.tar.gz, and ran "sudo python setup.py install".

**Problem:** "import django" says "ImportError: No module named django"

I guess django got installed to the system's Python2.6.6, how to install it into my local Python2.5 directory?

Comment: Gotta love gentoo's package slot handling and its management of multiple python versions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install python2.5 with synaptic, then you will be able to use easy_install2.5 to install django. If you don't have the python2.5 in your package list you can put django on your python2.5 system path and be with it

to view the system path do:

> python2.5 
>   import sys
>   sys.path

Comment: That's the case with newest ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! I located the place where to put Django... now sorry but what do I mean to copy? The whole unarchived Django-1.2.5.tar.gz or just the "django" directory within it?

Comment: Done, I needed to copy the "django" directory within Django-1.2.5.tar.gz to python2.5/Lib thanks again!